# How can I change file types of multiple files at once?

Tags: 14.04, files, file-type

I would like to change file type of multiple files at once. 
The files are like A.1, A.2, A.3 ...
and I want them to be A.01, A.02, A.03 ...

It's kind of weird file type, but that's just how my program outputs results.

I use Ubuntu 14.04 for your information.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: you mean file name, not file type, right?

Comment: I think this user is not aware that filename extension doesn't matter  on Linux. So, it's simple renaming of a file , that's all.

Comment: @Arnold so you want all filenames to have two character extension, or you simply want to have leading zero ? what if you have A.100, do you want it to become A.0100 ?  Please clarify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although there are simpler ways in this particular case, the *general* approach I'd take is to re-print the numeric suffix with your desired field width and padding - either using the shell's `printf` function

```
for f in A*; do 
  printf -v fnew '%s.%02d' "${f%.*}" "${f##*.}"
  echo mv -v -- "$f" "$fnew"
done
```

(remove the `echo` once you've checked that it's doing the right thing) or with the perl-based `rename`/`prename`

```
prename -vn -- 's/\.(\d+)$/sprintf ".%02d", $1/e' A*
```

(this time, remove the `n` to actually rename).

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming:

- you just want to insert `0` after the `.` in all the filenames
- `A` represents whatever is before the `.` and it is the same every time and has no special characters (for example, there is only one `.`)

If this is true it is very easy to replace `A.` with `A.0` in all the file names.

(However, you should definitely do what steeldriver says, as there's no doubt it's an entirely superior method)

Make sure you are in the directory where the files are (open a terminal and `cd` to the right directory, or navigate to it in Nautilus and then right click and select "open in terminal") by doing `ls` - you should see the files you want to rename. You can use a `for` loop

```
for f in A*; do mv "$f" "${f/A./A.0}"; done
```

Or even easier, use `rename`

```
rename 's/A\./A.0/' A*
```

Comment: This rename is dangerous, regex match for "."  Is anything. Best to warn user, I doubt his files are named exactly that way.

Comment: @Zanna You should consider using `\.` to match literal `.` in regular expressions. More information: http://serverfault.com/a/228738/223390

Comment: @Zanna the `.` only needs to be escaped in the perl (regex-based) version I think; in the shell version, the `.` matches a literal period (the 'any single character' pattern in a shell glob is `?`). You should get into the habit of quoting your variables though i.e. `"$f"` and `"${f/A./A.0}"`